# Significance of Negative reference voltage in DAC0808 Chip

Tags: voltage-measurement, dac

In [DAC0808](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac0808.pdf), positive reference voltage is used to set the maximum output current through that chip and the value of the output current can be changed by appropriately setting the bits. Normally, in that configuration we ground the Negative reference voltage pins. So, as it's name indicate negative and reference, is it used to set the current in the output pin? what's the significance of it in DAC0808. I searched in the datasheet but couldnt get enough information, only a diagram regarding it's use is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the schematic on page 6 "equivalent circuit of the DAC" you can see the V- input goes into a PNP based differential (long-tailed) pair.

Even from the naming you can see it is the negative polarity of a differential input.  Is is *NOT* the negative reference.  It is the reference negative.

[image]